# VB: Type Mismatch Error, Array Dimensions 1x1

Tags: arrays, vba, dimensions, type-mismatch

I am trying to use a `Variant` datatype to store an array of strings. This is an example of the code I am using.

```
Sub Selecto()

Dim numRows As Integer    
Dim Badger As Variant

numRows = InputBox("How many rows?", "Rows",0)
Badger = Range("C21:C"& 21 -1 + numRows).Value    

For i = 1 To UBound(Badger)
    MsgBox (Badger(i, 1))
Next

End Sub
```

My goal is to make it so that `Badger` is an array whose length can be defined by the user running the macro via the InputBox. The code works just fine, except when the value of `numRows` entered is 1 it spits out a "type mismatch error".

The error causes the line `For i=1 to UBound(Badger)` to be highlighted and the error message box says that there is a "type mismatch".

I'm guessing that for a 1-by-1 array, the data is simply stored as a string rather than as an array and that array functions like `Ubound()` and array index syntax like `Badger(i,1)` don't work. Is that the case? Is there a way to force it to recognize that variable as an array?

Comment: Shouldn't your arrays be starting with 0 instead of 1

Comment: If numRows=1 then you don't get an array, but a single value. If numRows>1 then you get a 1-based 2-d array, so you need to pass to UBound the dimension you want to get the value for.  So: `UBound(Badger,1)` will give you the number of "rows" in your array. Also, you may have inadvertently caused some confusion by tagging your question with vb.net...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the VB.NET tag, Tim.

Answer (score 5):

If only one value is read from the range then the variant doesn't create an array, which is why you get a type mismatch when trying to index it.  Try checking if `Badger` is an array with `IsArray(Badger)`.  The code below works when I use it:

```
Sub Selecto()
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim Badger As Variant

    numRows = InputBox("How many rows?", "Rows", 0)

    Badger = Range("C21:C" & 21 - 1 + numRows).Value

    If IsArray(Badger) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(Badger)
            MsgBox (Badger(i, 1))
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox Badger
    End If
End Sub
```